# Working in PHP textarea is too slow, huge amount of texts in it

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea

I'm still new with PHP and I was wondering if this issue is normal and if there's a work around for it.

I have a PHP page wherein there's a textarea and the user must open a server log txt file, copy everything in it, then paste it on the PHP page's text area. The problem is working with the textarea especially when it contains too many characters (and probably some hidden characters) runs too slow. Like cutting/deleting part of the text will freeze the page for minutes. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Like a settings or something.

Comment: This is not a PHP issue. The web browser is having trouble rendering that much text inside of a `<textarea></textarea>`. So you have two choices: get a faster PC or don't paste so much text into a `<textarea>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a problem with the web browser UI, there is no way to keep this from being slow. You need to come up with a way of getting around having the user paste a boatload of text into a `textarea`.

One way could be to replace the input field with a file upload so that the user could upload the txt file directly.

Comment: Thanks, so making the user upload the text file instead of pasting it in a textarea reduces the processing time?

Comment: Yes, because the browser never has to think about displaying the text, it just sends the data directly to the server. UI operations are usually more expensive than anything else on the frontend.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clearing that out, I will find a way for the user to upload the txt log file then for the PHP to read it. Thanks for guiding me to the correct path.